# in Ruby, conversion of float integer into %H %M %S time

Tags: ruby, time

How do you convert a float, say 13.5, to the corresponding 24-hour time %H:%M:%S? 
(13.5 would be 13:30:00, 8.25 would be 8:15:00)
I'm still figuring the Time class...it confuses me

Comment: First convert those into seconds by calculating hours and minutes then use the following 
you can use Time.at(<seconds>).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

Answer (score 7):

```
sec = (13.5 * 3600).to_i
min, sec = sec.divmod(60)
hour, min = min.divmod(60)
"%02d:%02d:%02d" % [hour, min, sec] # => "13:30:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Time of your with two digit in minutes like 5 to 50
time_val="13.50"
#split by "."
split_val=time_val.split('.')
#get a hours 
hour_val=split_val[0]
#get a minutes
min_val= (100*60)/split_val[1].to_i
if(min_val == 60)
   hour_val +=1
   min_val=0
end
#it's concat a hours and minutes then it's final result
final_time= hour_val.to_s + ":" + min_val + ":00"
```

Comment: This will not work for all the cases. For an input '13.99', it will give '13:60:00', but it should be '14:00:00'. right?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for comment.please chexck it updated answer